# Cannot convert the second argument of the initializer-list

Tags: c++

The Standard says: (`N3797::13.3.3.1/4 [over.best.ics]`)

> However, when considering the argument of a constructor or
>   user-defined conversion function that is a candidate by 13.3.1.3 when
>   invoked for the copying/moving of the temporary in the second step of
>   a class copy-initialization, by 13.3.1.7 when passing the initializer
>   list as a single argument or when the initializer list has exactly one
>   element and a conversion to some class `X` or reference to (possibly
>   cv-qualified) `X` *is* considered for the *first* parameter of a constructor
>   of `X`, [...] only standard conversion sequences and ellipsis conversion sequences are considered.

That's we're concerned about the first argument only in the following case:

```
#include <iostream>

struct B;

struct C
{
    C(){ }
    C(const B&){ }
};

struct B
{ 
    B(){ }
    B(const C&){ }
};

struct A
{
    A(const C&, const C&){ }
    A(const B&){ }
};

B b;
C c;
A a{b, b};


int main(){ }
```

**[DEMO](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/52e1809738ba1057)**

It works, although I provided `b` as the first argument and the user-defined conversion `B-->C` shouldn't be applied.

Comment: How do you expect this example to work? By what sequence of conversions do you expect the compiler to turn an instance of `B` into a `const C&`?

Comment: @IgorTandetnik You're right. It wouldn't work. But why does http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/52e1809738ba1057 work fine? User defined conversion `B-->C` shouldn't be applied.

Comment: Why shouldn't user-defined conversion be applied?

Comment: @IgorTandetnik But C(const B&) is an user-defined conversion. It shouldn't be applied because of _only standard conversion sequences and ellipsis conversion sequences are considered._

Comment: You aren't doing copy-initialization. Nor are you passing initializer-list as a single argument. Nor does the initializer-list have exactly one element. The paragraph you cite has no bearing on your example.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik In the example http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/26e8866ce187407a initializer list has exactly one element, but it still works.

Comment: That example passes a `B` to a constructor taking a `B`. No conversion is involved, user-defined or otherwise.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Indeed, thanks. But It's a bit unclear when passing initializer list as a single argument. I thought it was just _A a{b, b}_ in my case. Here {b,b} is the initializer list. Couldn't you clarify?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. What exactly do you find unclear?

Comment: @IgorTandetnik You said that A a{b,b} was not the passing initializer list as the single argument. So, how can we pass initializer list as the single argument?

Comment: `A a({b, b});` or `A a{{b, b}};`.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Then the exapmple http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b3c4c081de33499a shouldn't work... but it works. I'm confused....

Comment: I'm confused, too. My reading of the standard is that it shouldn't compile. Per **8.5/16**, `A a({b, b})` is a *direct-initialization*, with *expression-list* consisting of a single *braced-init-list* `{b, b}`. Per **8.5/17** and **13.3.1.3**, this performs an overload resolution over all constructors. Per **13.3.2**, only constructors that can be called with one parameter are viable; this should exclude `A(const C&, const C&)` as a viable candidate.

Answer (score 0):

You have a conversion from a `B` to an `A` and a conversion from a `C` to a `B` but you are trying to construct an `A` from `{B,C}` and there is no constructor of that form. . .

But now you've chanded it completely. :)